# Expected value of e^-2x

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I have the following problem:

> The expectation of an exponentially distributed random variable $X$ is
> equals to $1/2$. Compute $\mathbb{E}[e^{-2x}]$.

The final answer is: $1/2$

I already know that $\mathbb{E}[x]$ of an exponential distribution equals $1/λ$. So $λ=2$.

That makes the probability density function: $f(x) = 2e^{-2x}$

I also know that $\mathbb{E}[e^{-2x}]$ equals the integral of $e^{2x} \cdot f(x)$. But when I solve this equation I get $(-1/2)\cdot e^{-4x}$.

Can I get feedback to get the final solution?

Ter

Comment: Maybe you have calculated the indefinite integral and you just have to put in the values $0$ and $\infty$ and subtract these.

Comment: Yes, I solved it! thanks :)

Comment: But how do you know you should take the boundries from 0 to ∞ ? How do you know it shouldn't be from -∞  to ∞ or from -∞  to 0?

Comment: The density of an exponentially distributed random variable is zero for values less than zero.

Comment: I see, tnx! @Philipp123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are told
$$X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$$
Therefore,
$$\mathrm{E}[X]=\frac{1}{\lambda}$$
For justification on this, see [here].(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)
Then, since we are told that $\mathrm{E}[X]=\frac{1}{2}$, we conclude $\lambda=2$. So
$$f_X(x)=2e^{-2x}.$$
Then, using [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician),
$$\mathrm{E}[e^{-2X}]=\int_{0}^{\infty}{2e^{-2x}\cdot 2e^{-2x}\mathrm{d}x}=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

$Ee^{-2X}=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-2x} 2 e^{-2x}dx=\frac 1 2 $.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{-2x}]=\int_0^{+\infty}2 e^{-4x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{+\infty}4 e^{-4x}dx=\frac{1}{2}$$

the integral

$$\int_0^{+\infty}4 e^{-4x}dx=1$$

because it is the integral of a $Exp(4)$ in all its domain

....anyway it i not difficult to calculate it and verify

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand untill the 2nd step. 2/-4 = -1/2. So why is the solution of the integral not -1/2*exp(-4x)?. How it it possible that the integral sign is still there in the final step?

Comment: @Terr070 : I edited my anwer with further explanation